# Using polymorphic paths with nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association that looks like this:

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
end

class Education < ActiveRecord::base
   has_many :lines, :as => :item
end

class Work < ActiveRecord::base
   has_many :lines, :as => :item
end
```

I'd like a simple way to create a new Line from the parent Item. So, I might be editing a view for a Work object, and want to have a link that creates a new Line object. Normally, I would do this:

```
<%= link_to "New Line", new_work_line_path(@work) %>
```

And the helper would work the route for this. However, this requires that I check which parent the Line belongs to in the controller, defeating the purpose of polymorphism (I could have used two references if that were the case). So, my question is, how do I get the path to work polymorphically like a normal path helper?

Comment: "What I'm looking for is a way to be in a view for, say, a work object, and create new Line to go in it." This sentence confuses me greatly. Care to rephrase?

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible way could be to use routes like this:

```
map.resources :works do |works|
  works.resources :lines
end

map.resources :educations do |edu|
  edu.resources :lines
end
```

Your LinesController remains the same, and you'll get routes like these:

```
work_lines GET    /works/:work_id/lines
....
education_lines GET    /educations/:education_id/lines
...
```

The most annoying part is to manage the first id passed, because you'll have a `params[:id]` referred to a Line, but you'll also have `params[:work_id]` or `params[:education_id]`. Here you must choose between checking which param is passed, or at least parse the requested url to determine in which you are (Works, Educations, etc...).

Hope this helped ;)

**EDIT:**

According to what emerged in comments, you can use `polymorphic_url`/`polymorphic_path` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

It makes sense if you use them like this way:

```
link_to "New Line", polymorphic_url(@line.item,@line)
# => /<educations_or_works>/item_id/lines/line_id
```

At least, you can even use it for collections:

```
link_to "New Line", polymorphic_url(@line.item,Line.new)
# => /<educations_or_works>/item_id/lines/
```

Cheers,
a.

Comment: This is a way to do this, but it's not polymorphic at all. I've found a lot of variations on this, and it seems like polymorphic associations were included in ActiveRecord, but completely forgotten in every other place. I was hoping that wasn't actually the case, and I just looked in the wrong places. I'll keep this in mind if I can't find anything else, though.

Comment: I showed you routes mantaining your polymorphyc model associations.

Comment: right, but the routes don't behave polymorphically, which is what I'm looking for. The route is specific to whether the Line belongs to a Work or an Education, as is the result in the controllor (:word_id and :education_id). Because both of these are supposed to be associated with lines as an Item object, it would make sense if there were a way to get an :item_id in there that could represent either Work or Education.

Comment: Thank you ^_^ Thats the perfect answer.

Comment: Just tumbled onto this.... if you are still on Rails 2.3.x (2.3.5 in my case), then the correct way to call the method is polymorphic_path|url([@line.item, @line])... noting the array parameter

Comment: link_to "New Line", polymorphic_url([@line.item,:lines]) should also work.

Comment: polymorphic_path(@menu_item.menuable) Worked like a charm! Thank you!