# What's a DRY solution for routes and controller with a polymorphic resource attached to both of a pair of nested resources?

Tags: resources, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, polymorphism

Disclaimer: first month of developing with rails, but I have read everything I could find.

Edit: Somehow I missed [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145976/using-polymorphic-paths-with-nested-associations) with a similar final answer.

I have polymorphic flags:

```
Class Flag...
  belongs_to :flaggable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

I have nested resources that have the appropriate has_many :flags, :as => :flaggable statement.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

I would like both posts and comments and in the future other things on the site to be flaggable. **What is the DRY/standard way (I'm using Rails 3.1) to do this with regard to routes and controller?**

---

What I did for routes:

Mostly based on [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association), I made flags as a nested resource of both posts and comments. Already, I think I'm on the wrong track because it seems to be re-stating the polymorphic relationships in the models as well as breaking the guideline that ["Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

```
resources :posts do
  resources :flags
  resources :comments do
    resources :flags
  end
end
```

Alternatively, I thought to implement the flaggable routes separately as below. But again, this doesn't seem DRY and additionally makes non-desired independent routes for comments.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :flags
end
resources :comments do
  resources :flags
end
```

Finally, I wondered if I could make a generic resource for flaggables. I couldn't find any way to implement this and it has the same problem of the previous method of making general routes available for the generic flaggable type.

```
resources :flaggable do
  resources :flags
end
```

---

What I did for the controller for the nested resources above:

I implemented find_flaggable, but realized that with nested resources, the parameter that gets converted to a flaggable class could be either Post or Comment since both end up in parameters (post_id and comment_id). I could solve the below with an id priority list for the current setup, but that is not a general solution and makes it even less DRY than it already is.

```
def find_flaggable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

---

So this is where I stopped (actually implemented a limited solution only for Posts and Comments) and realized I don't know a satisfying way to accomplish this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to solve the bit of DRYing up the code in your routes, a simple way would be to use

```
[:posts, :comments, :yet_another_resource].each do |resource_type|
  resources resource_type do
    resources :flags
  end
end
```

instead of

```
resources :posts do
  resources :flags
end
resources :comments do
  resources :flags
end
```

This starts becoming really clean and useful when you have a lot of actions under your nested resources. Sort of like a simple version of the "Extract method" refactoring for your routes.

EDIT

In case you missed my comment, I think [polymorphic_url](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/55-generate-polymorphic-url) is the right thing you are looking for!!

Comment: That's a nice technique. Thank you. I have two questions for you. 1) Doing it that way I think has the same issue as my second routes method: it makes top level resources/routes out of some resources that I don't want to be. Is there some option to disable those routes and just enable the child routes? 2) Do you have any suggestions about the controller and a general way to handle flagging resources that may or may not be nested? Or some other approach?

Comment: Hmm to be honest I find it a bit hard to understand your complete question. But I think what you might be looking for is polymorphic_url as try something like what [described here](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/55-generate-polymorphic-url), since you are using a polymorphic relation.

Comment: Sorry the question may not be very good since I'm new to rails, but I wonder what part is unclear. The polymorphic path is nice. It gets to the controller. In the flag controller, I think there is still the issue of creating a flag without a priori knowledge of the base resource though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only trying to flag article instead of manipulate a flag resource collection I would just create a `flag` method in the Controllers on the resources you might want to flag.

From there you can just build the flag from the resource itself.

```
class PostsController < ApllicationController
  ...

  def flag
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    flag = @post.flags.build(params[:flag])

    if flag.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post flagged"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Unable to flag post"
    end
    render @post
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
 resources :posts do
   post 'flag', :on => member
   resources :comments do
     post 'flag', :on => member
   end
 end
```

Something like that should work, it's not the DRYest way to do it. But it's probably how I would implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I believe it's similar to the first routes solution I put but moves the explicit (non-polymorphic) decisions out of the Flag controller into each flaggable controller where the priority of ids would be inherently obvious. Good idea.

Comment: I'm going to wait a while longer to see if anyone has a more generalized solution, and then mark yours as the solution if not. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, but I would be a little weary of moving the flagging action to another controller, if you did that you would be passing parameters to another controller. Where as it seems like flagging should be handled by the object that you want to flag. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: To put Azolo's comments above into context, I removed the :only => :create option to make flags general resources so the answer can hopefully bemore general.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Here is what I ended up using, although I'm not totally satisfied with it. It seems like half-made polymorphism since the polymorphic resource's parent actually needs to be directly "typed" somewhere along the line. In jake's solution within the controller. In Azolo's by the routing of flags into various controllers. I had hoped to find a way to let Rails do the typing and simplify the application code.

To answer my first question about routes, it seems that no one is bothered about having unused routes caused by putting, for example, comments at a base level with flags as a child resource (as in Jake's answer). So I took Jake's answer there as the way to setup the routes. The polymorphic path helpers are nice too.

```
[:posts, :comments, :yet_another_resource].each do |resource_type|
  resources resource_type do
    resources :flags
  end
end
```

That would then lead to using a flag controller that accepts the various polymorphic path helpers with something like find_flaggable from the railscast in my question.

```
def find_flaggable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Thanks again for the help.